# Android AltBeacon library stop find beacons every 1 second when app in background on galaxy s7

Tags: android, altbeacon, samsung-galaxy

I'm using AltBeacon library inside service to find my beacon every 1 second when the app on foreground. 
On Galaxy s7 when the app go's to background it stop find the beacon every second,
instead it return data every few seconds between 5 - 30 secs.
I can see that "didRangeBeaconsInRegion" call every second but it return with out beacons most of the time.

I need to keep the behavior of foreground when the app is in background.

This is my BeaconManager configuration:

```
private static long EXIT_PERIOD = 16500;
private static long SCAN_PERIOD = 1150;
.
.
.
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
BeaconManager.setRegionExitPeriod(EXIT_PERIOD);
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(SCAN_PERIOD);
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(SCAN_PERIOD);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

**Some builds of Android 7.x for Samsung devices put Bluetooth scans into low power mode when an app has no activities in the foreground.**  The reason you see Les frequent detections is because that is how low power scans on Android behave.

You can read more about this issue here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/483

To be clear, this is appears to be a Samsung-specific customization to Android.  **There is no known workaround to keep the OS from overriding a low latency scan with a low power one.**